# How to trigger an image to fadein IF a div is not clicked after a certain time?

Tags: jquery

I'd like an image (`.stickman`) to `fadeIn` if another image (`.lighSwitchOff`) on the site isn't clicked within a certain amount of time (5sec). I'm having trouble finding any specific help for this. Is there an opposite for `.click`?

As in:

```
$(".lightSwitchOff").notclicked(5000 (function(){
    $(".stickman").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you could use a timer to fade in the `.stickman` element after the specified time and clear that timer if the `.lighSwitchOff` element is clicked, something like this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.stickman').fadeIn();
}, 5000);

$('.lighSwitchOff').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a treat! Just had to add CSS: .stickman {display:none}.

Answer (score 0):

First set a variable or data attribute on click event.

Say I am setting the window variable

```
window.info =  true;
$(".lightSwitchOff").click(function() {
    window.info = false;
});
```

Now check after certain period of time using `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.info) {
        $(".stickman").fadeIn();
    }
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Same as the other answer using an `int` - you should use the correct variable type - a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own plugin like below, extending jQuery.

```
$.fn.notClicked = function(options, callback) {
  var $this = this;
  $this.timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {  //check if callback param is a function
      callback.call(this);  //trigger callback
    }
  }, options);
  $(this).click(function(){
      clearTimeout($this.timeOut);
  });
}

$(".lightSwitchOff").notClicked(5000, function() {
  $(".stickman").fadeIn();
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/15/)**

Comment: This appears to be `$.fn.runAfter` or `$.fn.delayedStart` - can't see how actually clicking stops the event from running.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Ahh! Sorry. I have no idea why my edit did not commit 2 hours ago. Anyways, rewrote and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/n9vj0hzp/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ffffff&text=Light+Switch+Off" class="lighSwitchOff" /><br>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ffffff&text=Stick+Man" class="stickman" />
```

**CSS**

```
.stickman{
  display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;
  $('.lighSwitchOff').on('click', function(){
    count=1;

  });



  setTimeout(function(){ 

  if(count==0)
  $('.stickman').fadeIn();

  }, 5000);


});
```

Comment: You should use the correct variable type, not always an integer.  `var clicked=false;..clicked=true... if(!clicked)`